# Where can I find configuration guide for QPID Broker-J?

Tags: qpid

I am trying to use Qpid as inmemory AMQP broker for integration testing. I am having hard time on finding out how to configure it via configuration file since there is no description of config file in the documentation.

https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-broker-j-7.1.9/book/Java-Broker-Initial-Configuration.html

Documentation is in form like "here is configuration file, you can use it" without any explanation of how to actually do it? What are the props? What does they do? Example configuration is just pasted in without any explainatio of what those settings are doing (eg what `{"name": "nameAlias","type": "nameAlias"}` actually do?). There is no described structure of config file nor nested config (which is a json itselft that has to be escaped) for virtual host.

Thats an absurd.

Is there any kind of description on how config should look alike and what can it/cannot do?